# Docker Installation on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo) x86_64

Tags: linux, docker, rhel7

I am trying to install Docker CE on the RHEL 7.9 server, but I am getting a blow error.

```
sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: download.docker.com; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.


 One of the configured repositories failed (Docker CE Stable - x86_64),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=docker-ce-stable ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable docker-ce-stable
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=docker-ce-stable

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=docker-ce-stable.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from docker-ce-stable: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: download.docker.com; Unknown error"
```

I have tried URL with Curl
curl https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: download.docker.com; Unknown error

but when i try this URL in the brower, its working fine

Comment: Looks like a boring old DNS problem. Can you resolve other hosts? Does `curl https://api.ipfy.org/` work?

Comment: I have tried as you suggested. curl https://api.ipfy.org
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT